# Extract digits from mixed types column which has unknown structure, using a vector that contains the matching digits

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I have one mixed types column (string and digits with different structures) in my spark tibble [spark_tbl1] that might potentially contain digit codes for each row. I got another tibble [spark_tbl2] that actually list the digit codes (about 6000 rows ) I want to extract from the [spark_tbl1].

The problem is that the two tibbles don't have any key in common. What would be a clever way to solve this problem. Down-below is an example:

```
#This is my spark_tbl1 which contains the mmixed types column
#I limit rows to 3 (I got actually 1.6E6 rows)

df=data.frame(mixed_types_colum=c("ZB0R2298000","BZRT929700","FTUI06970T"),
                another_column=c("Banana","Apple","Orange"))
spark_tbl1=sdf_copy_to(sc,df,"df1",overwrite = TRUE)
spark_tbl1%>%head()
# Source: spark<spark_tbl1> [?? x 2]
  mixed_types_colum another_column
  <chr>             <chr>         
1 ZB0R2298000        Banana        
2 BZRT929700         Apple         
3 FTUI06970T        Orange
```

```
#This tibble is supposed to have more than 6000 rows.
df2=data.frame(digit_code=c("298","297","697"))
spark_tbl2=sdf_copy_to(sc,df2,"df2",overwrite = TRUE)
spark_tbl2%>%head()
# Source: spark<spark_tbl2> [?? x 1]
  digit_code
  <chr>     
1 298       
2 297       
3 697
```

I expect the output :

```
spark_tbl2%>%head()
# Source: spark<spark_tbl2> [?? x 3]
  mixed_types_colum another_column digit_code
  <chr>             <chr>          <chr>     
1 ZB0R2298000       Banana         298       
2 BZRT929700        Apple          297       
3 FTUI06970T        Orange         697
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: More than 6000 is also 1 million. I presume you mean around 6000.

Comment: Actually, the tibble [spark_tibble2] has around 6000 distinct values of digit codes that might potentially appear in the 1.6 millions  distinct values of the mixed types column from [spark_tibble1]

Comment: may be an idea to follow protocol and select an answer, or comment otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally from Scala perspective, so you will need to adapt accordingly:

1. Partition your tbl1 into large num partitions, df.
2. Create a List l from tbl2.

   ```
   val l = ...toList
   ```
3. Do a withColumn function in some way, e.g.

   ```
   df.withColumn("some col",
                  col("your col").rlike(l.mkString("|"))
                )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to find for each digit code in `df2` the corresponding rows in `df`. Then one might (lazily) wrap this in a `lapply` in order to iterate over the rows (there are probably cleverer ways here), e.g.

```
 do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df2), 
                       function(k) cbind(df[grep(df2$digit_code[k], df$mixed_types_colum),], 
                                         df2$digit_code[k])
                 )
         )
# output
#   mixed_types_colum another_column df2$digit_code[k]
# 1       ZB0R2298000         Banana               298
# 2        BZRT929700          Apple               297
# 3        FTUI06970T         Orange               697
```

where `df,df2` are defined as above (as the library used for the other data frames is not specified).

Comment: I use  Sparklyr library in Rstudio. I processed this way but the resulting sql query is too deep with around 6000 "rows stacking". When I try just to see the  first observations my Spark session freezes